# Entity Framework Shared Core Functionality Library

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am programming a few projects which have some core functionality which are similar and then their own functionality outside of that.

I was considering making a class library, using Entity Framework with Code First in order to provide some shared functionality and the database tables that go with it.

For example, I may want to use the class library to send an email and then use entity framework to log in a database table that an email is sent.

This class library would be added into another project, which also uses entity framework - in the same database. So now I would like the database to "build itself", creating the email logging table and some other functionality, e.g. products of some sort.

I have not used Entity Framework before, will having two dlls end up causing any kind of confusion because they're both pointing to the same database but expect different tables? e.g. would they be inclined to delete tables because they don't appear in the code?

Will it also cause problems if I end up over-lapping, e.g. if I want to do a join on all products (Project Entity Framework) which have had an email (Class Library Entity Framework) sent out, would I be able to do a join via linq?

Comment: Why not just have a "Database" project that thoroughly encapsulates all your data access to a particular database and just share that between projects?

Comment: The problem is that perhaps 60-80% of the data will be the same, but there will be differences in columns and tables for each project - as well as the queries (One project will be more complicated than the other). I would therefore need to have redundant tables, columns and queries for each project if I was to use a single database project.

Comment: But you asked, "will having two dlls end up causing any kind of confusion because they're both pointing to the same database".  How could you be pointing to the *same* database if different projects will have different columns for the same tables?

Comment: I mean that, for Project A, it would have it's own edmx file pointing to Database A (compiled into dll) and it will also reference Library B - with it's own edmx file, pointing to Database A. I was concerned that it would attempt to drop tables that weren't expected or that I could not do any cross-edmx joins. Maybe I could specify the same namespace for both so that it builds like a partial file?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to keep everything in one `DbContext`. You can do this by using interfaces to group the entities in each dll, then declare a concrete DbContext class that combines them all in your top-level code.

Project1:

```
public interface IMyProj1DbContext : IDbContext
{
    DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    DbSet<Place> Places { get; set; }
}
```

Project2:

```
public interface IMyProj2DbContext : IDbContext
{
    DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

And you'll need a third project that defines the common members:

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

Now in the code where all these come together, you can declare a single DbContext class that inmplements all of the interfaces:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyProj1DbContext, IMyProj2DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Place> Places { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you will want to write the code that uses the two different contexts and that code will live inside the individual dlls for each context. But how can you do that?

```
public class PersonFinder
{
    public Person FindPersonByLocation(Place placeToSearch)
    {
        using (var db = new ???)
        {
            return db.People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Location_Id == placeToSearch.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

You can't reference the concrete `DbContext` here because that will cause a circular dependency. The key is to inject the `DbContext` object at run-time:

```
public class PersonFinder : Disposable
{
    IMyProj1DbContext _db;

    public PersonFinder(IMyProj1DbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public Person FindPersonByLocation(Place placeToSearch)
    {
        return _db.People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Location_Id == placeToSearch.Id);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // ... Proper dispose pattern implementation excluded for brevity
        if (_db != null && _db is Disposable)
            ((Disposable)_db).Dispose();
    }
}
```

*This is not the best way to inject a disposable object, by the way. But it is relatively safe to do it this way and it demonstrates the principle without the extra clutter.

Now you only have one DbContext and EF will generate and maintain one single database, even though you have nice logical domain silos that can operate independently.

When you want to perform a join between the silo entities you code can use the MyDbContext class directly.